# why stack width is larger than the thermal and viscous penetration depth in thermoacoustic refrigerator?

Tags: thermodynamics, acoustics

The thermal and viscous penetration depth is smaller than the spacing in the stack:this assumption leads to the simplification of Rott‟s functions, where the complex hyperbolic tangents can be set equal to one.

i didn't understand what it implies!!please anyone help me to sort this out